# Content loading with Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like some content to be loaded into my div on page load, but then I would like to have buttons which will load up new content, and replace the content in the DIV currently.

This is my HTML:

```
<a id="aboutlink" href="#">About</a>
<a id="infolink" href="#">Info</a>
<div id="contentbox">Starting content</div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aboutlink').click(function(){
        $('#contentbox').load('/includes/about-info.html');
    });
    $('#testlink').click(function(){
        $('#contentbox').load('/includes/test-info.html');
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/GCg4V/1/

I just wondered what I have done wrong, because when I tried this on my server it didn't load up any content. I was also wondering if there is a better way to achieve something like this, because it doesn't seem like I can do any loading binding to it.

Thank you for any help or advice you can give.

Comment: 1) `testlink` != `infolink` 2) add `event.preventDefault()` to ensure your links will not get into action

Comment: Are the requests successful? have you checked using Chrome developer tools or similar? (of course it doesn't work in the jsFiddle because these resources don't exist there)

Comment: make sure 'load('/includes/about-info.html')' has proper path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method will only set the html of the first matched element if the status is `(200 OK)`.. If it is something other than this, like `(404 Not Found)` or `(403 Forbidden)` , then it won't set the html..

To set it regardless of the response, try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCg4V/2/) I edited.

Answer (score 1):

First try something like this:

```
$.get('/includes/test-info.html', data, function(data){alert(data);})
```

And then you'll be able to see exactly what is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Okay then run this code to check what happening out there:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#aboutlink').click(function () {
            $('#contentbox').load('/includes/about-info.html', function(response, status, xhr){
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
        $('#infolink').click(function () {
            $('#contentbox').load('/includes/test-info.html', function(response, status, xhr){
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });

    })  
</script>
<a id="aboutlink" href="#">About</a>
<a id="infolink" href="#">Info</a>
<div id="contentbox">Starting content</div>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is not the typo... even with the right id names it won't work when the response is not `200 OK` .

Comment: @MiroMarkarian: check new code to check what happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I think its something to do with how you have specified the urls for the load.
Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#aboutlink').click(function () {
        $('#contentbox').load('includes/about-info.html');
    });
    $('#infolink').click(function () {
        $('#contentbox').load('includes/test-info.html');
    });
})
```

without the leading "/"